# Pine Script: Sum() function is not working for Version 5 pine script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

Good day everyone, below is the pine script for the **Heatmap Volume indicator** for Version 4. When I apply it in Version 5, it shows **"Could not find function or function reference 'sum'"**, is it means that the sum function is not applicable in Version 5?

```
// Calculations
length2 := length2 > bar_index + 1 ? bar_index + 1 : length2
slength := slength > bar_index + 1 ? bar_index + 1 : slength

pstdev(Series, Period) =>
    mean = sum(Series, Period) / Period
    summation = 0.0
    for i=0 to Period-1
        sampleMinusMean = nz(Series[i]) - mean
        summation := summation + sampleMinusMean * sampleMinusMean
    result = sqrt(summation / Period)
```

May I know does it have **any other ways to modify it so that it suits the version 5 pine script**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sum() function in v4 was changed to math.sum() in v5.

```
pstdev(Series, Period) =>
    mean = math.sum(Series, Period) / Period
    summation = 0.0
    for i=0 to Period-1
        sampleMinusMean = nz(Series[i]) - mean
        summation := summation + sampleMinusMean * sampleMinusMean
    result = sqrt(summation / Period)
```